# Starwars text effect in WPF

Tags: wpf, animation

Our company executives have requested the integration of a "Star Wars crawl" style credits screen for our About box  in our application and I've been tasked to complete this within a week.

I'm not sure where to even start. I have a feeling the DoubleAnimation is where I'm meant to be looking, but how I make the text crawl up the screen and into a single point is where I'm a bit lost and how to fade the text out and move into the middle of the screen (like the STAR WARS bit).

Is this easy to do in WPF or should just get an animation going? The problem is that we have text that changes based on the installed version and user.

Comment: All the StarWars effects, fonts, etc should be included in the framework!

Answer (score 16):

Here's a quick sample I threw together for you. It uses 3D and doesn't seem to perform that well. But it works!

```
<Window
  x:Class="StarWars.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="480" Width="640" Background="Black">

  <Viewport3D ClipToBounds="True" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <Viewport3D.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Viewport3D.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation
              Storyboard.TargetName="Translation"
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="OffsetY"
              To="10"
              Duration="0:1:0" />
          </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
    </Viewport3D.Triggers>
    <Viewport3D.Camera>
      <PerspectiveCamera
        FarPlaneDistance="100"
        NearPlaneDistance="1"
        FieldOfView="30"
        LookDirection="0,25,-13"
        UpDirection="0,1,0"
        Position="0,2,1.5" />
    </Viewport3D.Camera>
    <ModelVisual3D>
      <ModelVisual3D.Content>
        <Model3DGroup>
          <Model3DGroup.Children>
            <AmbientLight Color="#FF808080" />
            <GeometryModel3D>
              <GeometryModel3D.Transform>
                <TranslateTransform3D
                  x:Name="Translation"
                  OffsetY="3" />
              </GeometryModel3D.Transform>
              <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
              <MeshGeometry3D
                Positions="-1,-2,0 1,-2,0 1,1,0 -1,1,0"
                TriangleIndices="0 1 2  0 2 3"
                TextureCoordinates="0,1 1,1 1,0 0,0"
                Normals="0,0,1 0,0,1" />
              </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
              <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial>
                  <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                    <VisualBrush>
                      <VisualBrush.Visual>
                        <TextBlock
                        Foreground="Yellow"
                        FontFamily="Consolas"
                        TextAlignment="Center">
                          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<LineBreak/>
                          consectetur adipiscing elit.<LineBreak/>
                          Integer malesuada, massa<LineBreak/>
                          vitae suscipit dictum, purus<LineBreak/>
                          dolor volutpat arcu, ac<LineBreak/>
                          tincidunt erat mauris sed nisi.<LineBreak/>
                          Sed ac eros ac augue<LineBreak/>
                          ullamcorper sodales sed id leo.<LineBreak/><LineBreak/>
                          Suspendisse nibh enim,<LineBreak/>
                          hendrerit vitae pretium et,<LineBreak/>
                          gravida in tortor. Lorem ipsum<LineBreak/>
                          dolor sit amet, consectetur<LineBreak/>
                          adipiscing elit. Maecenas<LineBreak/>
                          condimentum enim eu tellus<LineBreak/>
                          feugiat mollis ac ut arcu.<LineBreak/>
                          Ut fringilla tempus volutpat.<LineBreak/>
                          Duis elementum convallis<LineBreak/>
                          tincidunt.<LineBreak/><LineBreak/>

                          Mauris lacus tortor,<LineBreak/>
                          tristique nec congue at,<LineBreak/>
                          adipiscing sed eros.<LineBreak/><LineBreak/>

                          In volutpat eros id nunc<LineBreak/>
                          hendrerit eget aliquet nisi<LineBreak/>
                          lacinia.<LineBreak/><LineBreak/>

                          Suspendisse et lorem augue, non eleifend est.
                        </TextBlock>
                      </VisualBrush.Visual>
                    </VisualBrush>
                  </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                </DiffuseMaterial>
              </GeometryModel3D.Material>
            </GeometryModel3D>
          </Model3DGroup.Children>
        </Model3DGroup>
      </ModelVisual3D.Content>
    </ModelVisual3D>
  </Viewport3D>
</Window>
```

Comment: I would have awarded a +1 for at least using the actual Star Wars scrolling text...

Comment: Lorem ipsum was more accessible at the time ;) If I have time later, I'll show you how you can do the same effect by animating texture coordinates as well.

Answer (score 12):

Check my version. It has shading - when text comes over certain point it starts disapperating, like in original version (you can check on youtube)

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="500" Background="Black">
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Window.Loaded" >
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard Name="story">
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="TextPos" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="OffsetY" 
                        From="-1.5" To="5" Duration="0:1:30" RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>

    <Grid>
        <Viewport3D Name="viewport3D1" >
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera x:Name="camMain" Position="0.5 -1 0.4" LookDirection="0 5 -1">
                </PerspectiveCamera>
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <AmbientLight Color="White"></AmbientLight>

                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <GeometryModel3D>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshMain"
                                Positions="0.2 -5 0   0.8 -5 0   0.2 1 0   0.8 1 0"
                                TriangleIndices="0 1 3  0 3 2"
                                TextureCoordinates="0 1  1 1  0 0  1 0">
                            </MeshGeometry3D>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseMain" >
                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    <VisualBrush>
                                        <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                            <Grid Width="200" Height="1000" Background="Black">
                                                <Border BorderBrush="Black">
                                                    <TextBlock  Background="Black"
                                                             TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                             Foreground="#FFFFDA00" 
                                                             FontFamily="Franklin Gothic" 
                                                             FontWeight="Bold"
                                                             FontSize="16"
                                                             TextAlignment="Justify"
                                                             LineHeight="17"
                                                             LineStackingStrategy="BlockLineHeight"
                                                             >
                                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. <LineBreak/> <LineBreak/> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<LineBreak/> <LineBreak/>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<LineBreak/> <LineBreak/>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<LineBreak/> <LineBreak/>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.<LineBreak/> <LineBreak/>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                </Border>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                    </VisualBrush>
                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    </GeometryModel3D>                    
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
                <ModelVisual3D.Transform>
                    <TranslateTransform3D x:Name="TextPos" OffsetY="-1.5"/>
                </ModelVisual3D.Transform>
            </ModelVisual3D>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <GeometryModel3D>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                            <MeshGeometry3D x:Name="meshShadow"
                                Positions="0.2 0.5 0.1   0.8 0.5 0.1   0.2 5 0.1   0.8 5 0.1"
                                TriangleIndices="0 1 3  0 3 2"
                                TextureCoordinates="0 1  1 1  0 0  1 0">
                            </MeshGeometry3D>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
                        <GeometryModel3D.Material>
                            <DiffuseMaterial x:Name="matDiffuseShade" >
                                <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.85" />
                                        <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1.0" />
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                            </DiffuseMaterial>
                        </GeometryModel3D.Material>
                    </GeometryModel3D>
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This is awesome. Was able to adapt it for use in my app!

Comment: Thank you so much. We used an old and ugly Winforms hack to show the names of all developers und former ones as an easter-egg in our info-dialog if you double right clicked a special label. But forms is dead and so I used your code to host it as an user control in an element host and it looks so much nicer and only took me 5 minutes.

Comment: @TurnDrummer wow nice to hear that the post I wrote 7 years ago is still useful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2009/03/22/discovering-silverlight-3-the-star-wars-scroller.aspx) on a quick search. It's designed for Silverlight but you can port it easily to WPF. Even more it uses Blend in the example which is used for both WPF and Silverlight when it comes to UI design.

This should give you a starting point.

Regards...

Comment: this might not work in desktop WPF: read this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/9acb712a-b592-49e7-83a1-e3ee7ff03014 projection is feature of silverlight

Comment: Thanks for that, I already came across it but as found out I couldnt get it to work easily.

Comment: I'll try to make it work in WPF then, just for fun. If no solution comes around here I'll post the result here (if I can get it to work in WPF that is).